# Responsive element heights and typography in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am a newbie to web development and started working on Bootstrap-3 two months back. BS gives responsive "width" columns out of the box. But in my project, I have a few elements whose heights are also supposed to be responsive. Say I have a material card of width col-xs-6 col-sm-4 and I have set the default height as 210px for large screens. Now on small screens the width is adjusted automatically, but the height is obviously fixed, which ruins the design.

My requirements:

1. Adjust height of an element and it's inner divisions based on element's max height and width in different screen sizes.
2. The typography also seems to be static, so adjust font-size, line-height etc. based on screen size.
3. Also, I am trying to implement "multiline ellipses", I mean to trim text based on container height. I've had success in single line ellipses using white-space : now-wrap and text-ellipses : ellipses. But now I want to show few lines and then trim.

**The Code for Point number 1.**

```
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-card">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="#"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-figure">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="#"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class=""><a href="#">Username</a></p>
                            <a href="#" class="">50 Posts</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-thumbnails">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="#"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="#"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="#"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="#"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img src="#"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel.panel-card {
    height: 210px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.panel.panel-card .panel-heading {
    z-index: 2;
    height: 115px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: height 600ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 600ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 600ms ease-in-out;
    transition: height 600ms ease-in-out;
}
.panel.panel-card .panel-heading img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 120%;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}

.panel.panel-card .panel-figure {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);

    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.panel.panel-card .panel-figure img{
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.panel.panel-card .panel-body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

    -webkit-transition: padding 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: padding 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: padding 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: padding 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.panel.panel-card .panel-thumbnails {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.panel-thumbnails .thumb {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.panel-thumbnails .thumb img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.panel.panel-card:hover .panel-heading {
    height: 60px;

    -webkit-transition: height 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: height 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.panel.panel-card:hover .panel-figure {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.panel.panel-card:hover .panel-body {
    padding-top: 20px;

    -webkit-transition: padding 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: padding 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: padding 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: padding 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

You can find the original snippet [here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/tumblr-cards-redesign-concept)

It would be great if I can get some kind of a mixin or something to achieve this. I have been trying to fix this from past 3 weeks, but with no success, kindly help me with your suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: This is too broad. They are three different questions in a single one, without a single line of code. I doubt this will get answered successfully as it is now

Comment: @Andrea Ligios: Thanks for the heads up.......I have updated my question. You can see the classes .panel.panel-card and .panel.panel-card .panel-heading have fixed heights. Hope my question would be more clear now.